# Linear Algebra and subset of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space with basis $B$. Under what conditions will a subspace $U$ of $V$ that is not $V$ have a basis consisting of elements of $B$?

I'm wondering about this and know that it is generally not true, but when does it hold?

Comment: I think that I don't understand the question correctly. You don't want to hear the answer 'If and only if $U$ is the span of elements in $B$', or?.

Comment: @Nightgap that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That will happen if and only if $U$ is spanned by a subset of $B$.

In fact, if $B'\subset B$ and $U=\operatorname{span}(B')$, then $B'$ is a basis of $U$. On the other habd, if $B^\ast$ is a subset of $B$ which is a basis of $U$, then $U=\operatorname{span}(B^\ast)$.